# Does backing up a keycloak database backup everything?

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak, backup-strategies

I am wondering if simply backing up the keycloak database associated with postgres is enough so that if I every lose access to the keycloak instance. I can simply restore the database and everything will be smooth sailing?

P.S: I am using docker for keycloak

Thanks!